want to show info from one microservice to another
I have 3 services: User, Product and Tax.
all of these have userId, productId and taxId in them. each unique to them and only created in their own service.
Now I am trying to display data for all users, where they can have multiple properties but each property have only single tax related to it. So I have created everything according to it.

my entities
USER :
public class Users {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userId;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String propertyId;  // single user can have multiple property
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String taxId;   // single taxID for each propertyId
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    private String guardianName;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String adhaarCard;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String panCard;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yy")
    private LocalDate dob;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer age;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String address;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String role;
    
    @Transient
    private List<Property> properties =new ArrayList();

    @Transient
    private List<Tax> taxes =new ArrayList();   

}

PROPERTY
public class Property {
    
    private String propertyId;  // Unique Property ID (PIN)  , will be our primary key for this table
    
    private String userId;  // for user_id, whose property it is
    
    private String taxId;   // particular tax_id for that specific property
    
    private String ownerName;  // Owner's Name

    private String contactNumber;  // Contact Number

    private String address;  // Property Address

    private String tradeLicenseDetails;  // Trade license details if applicable
    
    @Transient
    private List<Tax> taxes =new ArrayList();

and TAX
public class Tax {
    
    private String taxId;  // Primary key for Tax Ledger entry

    private String propertyId;  // Foreign key from Property service

    private String userId;  // Foreign key from User service

    private double taxAmount;  // Amount of tax demanded

    private double amountPaid;  // Amount paid by the user

    private LocalDate paymentDate;  // Date when the payment was made
}

I have made them all unique and random also also made same entites in my DTO package for easier communication.
Now in my UserServiceImpl I am trying to displays all my user info regarding all their property and tax related to it.
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modalMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    private Property_Management_Service property_service;
    
    @Autowired
    private Tax_Management_Service tax_service;
    
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class); 
    
    
    @Override
    public UserDto createUser(UserDto userDto) {
        
        Users users = this.userDtoToUsers(userDto);    // modal mapper class for converting User entity to UserDTO entity

        Users saveUsers = this.userRepository.save(users);

        return this.usersTouserDto(saveUsers);
    }
    

    @Override
    public List<UserDto> getUser() {
        
        List<Users> users = this.userRepository.findAll();
                
        List<UserDto> userDtos = users.stream().map(user -> {
                    UserDto userDto = this.usersTouserDto(user);
                    
                    // Fetching properties for this user using property_ID
                        List<PropertyDto> propertyDtos = this.property_service.getPropertyById(user.getPropertyId());
                        userDto.setPropertiesDto(propertyDtos);
                    
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    // Fetch tax data for each property
                                    List<TaxDto> taxDtos = propertyDtos.stream().map(property -> {
                            return this.tax_service.getTaxById(property.getTaxId());
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

                        userDto.setTaxesDto(taxDtos);  // Set taxes in UserDto  
   
        return userDtos;
    }

the error I am getting in my above code is of "Single markers at this line - Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<ResponseEntity> to List"
and this is due to
Property_Management_Service
@FeignClient(name = "PROPERTY-DATA-MANAGEMENT")
public interface Property_Management_Service {
    
    // list all property data by property id
    @GetMapping("api/property/v1/property/{propertyId}")
    ResponseEntity<PropertyDto> getPropertyById(@PathVariable String propertyId);
}   

and Tax_Management_Service
@FeignClient(name = "TAX-DATA-MANAGEMENT")
public interface Tax_Management_Service {

    // list tax record data by tax_id
    @GetMapping("api/tax/v1/tax/{taxId}")
    ResponseEntity<TaxDto> getTaxById(@PathVariable String taxId);
    
}

My Error :

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceImpl': Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Project\Nagar Nigam\User-Data-Management\target\classes\com\user_dm\UM\services\UserServiceImpl.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.user_dm.UM.services.UserServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at com.user_dm.UM.UserDataManagementApplication.main(UserDataManagementApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Project\Nagar Nigam\User-Data-Management\target\classes\com\user_dm\UM\services\UserServiceImpl.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.user_dm.UM.services.UserServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:785) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.user_dm.UM.services.UserServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:221) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:94) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1331) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    propertyDtos cannot be resolved
    The method map(Function<? super Users,? extends R>) in the type Stream<Users> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> user) -> {})
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity<PropertyDto> to List<PropertyDto>
    Lambda expression's local variable taxDtos cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope. 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<ResponseEntity<TaxDto>> to List<TaxDto>

    at com.user_dm.UM.services.UserServiceImpl.<init>(UserServiceImpl.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:195) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


the error I am getting ... , post the stack trace

added @PeterMmm

updated code link
